# Firestore Rules using get returns insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm making a query to firestore using:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "vendors", this.vendorId), {
    title: "test listing",
    vendorId: this.vendorId
}, {merge: true}).then(i => {
    console.log("i", i)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log("error", e)
})
```

I have 2 collections the first one has a sub collection

**Collection users/${userId}**

```
{
    "userId": "123.uuu",
    "role": "vendor"
}
```

**Sub collection users/${userId}/vendors/${vendorId}**

```
{
    "user": "123.uuu",
    "vendor": "123..vvv"
}
```

The second collection is
**Collection vendors/${vendorId}**

```
{
    "userId": "123.uuu",
    "role": "vendor"
}
```

I want to be able to update the second collection **vendors/${vendorId}** but only if the users sub collection **users/${userId}/vendors/${vendorId}** exists and therefore has access to it.

The below rule doesn't work - returns **FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.**

```
match /vendors/{vendorId}{
    allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/vendors/$(vendorId)).data.user == request.auth.uid
}
```

Comment: Security rules don't mean anything unless paired with code that makes the query.  Please edit the question to show that code, so we can understand what exactly is failing.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the information you share.  Also please update the title of your post to describe the problem succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `allow update` will allow update operations only i.e. the document must already exist. Since you are using using `setDoc()`, that means a new document is being created if it doesn't exist already. Try allowing `create` as well:

```
allow create, update: if ....;
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) on Security Rules and also this [Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sOT5VOflvQ)

Comment: Makes sense! However, it didn't fix the problem. Still getting FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Doug Stevenson: "Security rules don't mean anything unless paired with code that makes the query.", you can try to follow the example code below that works upon replicating on my end:

```
// Where the user.uid is the users document id;
// and the vendorId is the value of the "user" under vendors' sub-collection
const userRef = doc(db, "users", {user.uid}, "vendors", {vendorId});
const userSnap = await getDoc(userRef);

if (userSnap.exists()){
  // Where the vendorId is the value of the user under vendors' collection
  await setDoc(doc(db, "vendors", {vendorId}), {
    title: "test listing",
    vendorId: this.vendorId
  }, 
    {merge: true}).catch(e => {
      console.log("error", e);
  })
}
else{
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}
```

Additionally, following the answer of @Dharmaraj, you can try this rule:

```
match /vendors/{vendorId} {
    // 'user' field in collection 'vendors', and users' sub-collection 'vendors', should have the same value for this rule to work
    // this will check 'vendors' and users' sub-collection 'vendors' user field if its the same or not
    allow read, create, update: if resource.data.user == request.auth.uid && request.auth.uid != null
}
```

For more information, you can check the guide below:

[How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)